# How can I include a resource file (logback.xml) in a project when building JAR but not when embedded in a WAR?

Tags: maven, logback

I'm working on a project that uses two maven projects (named `core` and `webapp`); `core` is built with JAR packaging and used for two different purposes: as a stand-alone app (essentially an executable JAR), and also embedded into `webapp`.

For its purpose as a stand-alone app, `core` needs to have its own logback configuration (a logback.xml file) that needs to be included on the classpath. Normal Maven convention would have me put it in `src/main/resources/logback.xml`. That works fine, but causes a problem when the `core` JAR is included in `webapp`. `webapp` needs to have its own logback configuration, but the container (tc Server or Jetty) is picking up the one from `core.jar` first.

I realize that logback can be told about a [custom config location via a system property](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty) (`-D` on the command line) but that's not viable in a app container like Tomcat or Jetty.

I've read some other people asking about this situation, but none of the solutions I've seen sits well with me. [One solution involved setting up a context listener that runs early in the webapp initialization](http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2013/03/renamed-logback-config-file-for-web.html) and explicitly configures logback based on a `<context-param>`. That's a bit brutish in my opinion, and probably a hard sell to my fellow dev team when log4j "just works" in this situation.

I'm far from a Maven expert, so I'm hoping there is some elegant way to get Maven to help me here. Or perhaps some logback extension or add-on that makes it more web-app friendly. Or even a clever idea that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that we ended up using was to leave only the common "non-app" pieces (code and configuration) in `core` and then extract the other "app" pieces into a new module (`batch-app`).
The logging configuration only lives in the 2 app projects (`webapp` and `batch-app`) that depend on `core`. `core` has a `logback-test.xml` configuration in it, but that's excluded from the JAR that maven builds (since it's in the `src/test/resources` folder).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible solutions, but the easiest is to put the file in its own module and mark the dependency as provided. The, conspire to have it on the classpath when running the standalone version of the app.

Comment: So are you saying  have a separate project that contains only the logback.xml configuration, have `core` depend on that (marked as `provided`)? Seems a bit heavy. Also, I'm not sure I can successfully ask to have the stand-alone command lines changed (it's uses by several batch processes that are managed by another team, unfortunately).

Comment: What you've really got is a shared library, and two applications that want to use the shared library.  To me this indicates 3 projects: the `core`, the webapp, and the standalone app.  The standalone app would include its own logback.xml file and the Main class at least.  This solution gives you flexibility to change the web & standalone apps independently as well.

Comment: @E-Riz Sure you can have the command-line changed -- that'll happen whenever you introduce a new third-party library too because otherwise how will the libs get onto the classpath. It may seem onerous, but it's normal so it's ok -- it would be unusual to have incremental development and refactoring not affect deployment in some way.

Comment: @user944849, that's true, this really is 2 apps that use a common JAR. I'm new to the team so have to sell the idea to the existing architect but I think it's worth it.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, we're using the onejar maven plugin to produce the executable JAR now, so there is no reason to change the batch jobs otherwise. Unfortunately the culture where I'm at isn't really ingrained with incremental or agile development, and there are organizational issues sometimes with getting other teams to participate. Having said that, I think I can sell the concept of separating this into 2 apps; it would mean a very small change to the batch jobs (basically, the name of the JAR they invoke).